# Can someone help me on this error. I can't clone from the Azure Devops to the local one

Tags: azure-devops, version-control

The Git repository with name or identifier sdsdsd  does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
fatal: repository 'https://dev.azure.com/azdevopsmar22/Version%20Controlling%20with%20Git%20in%20Azure%20Repos/_git/sdsdsd/'

Answer (score 0):

The error implies there is a security restriction on the Repo you are trying to access. Try one of the following:

- On windows, use windows credentials to add `git@https://<git-username>@dev.azure.com/<azdevopsmar22>`. Refer [this blog](https://blog.tylerdoerksen.ca/posts/2019/12/Azure-DevOps-Auth-Failures.html) ,
- [Azure devops check security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/about-permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)
- Within the AzureDevOps organization, your project, select settings --> Repository --> Select the repo that you have trouble accessing --> security. Check if read permissions are set on the group you belong to.